# Is it possible to use the STL for_each algorithm using a function with independent input parameters?

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm

At the moment I am running a for loop where I make a call on each element in an STL container, similar to the following.

```
void AddToUpdate(iterator iter, Update& Update) {...};

...

Update update;
for(iterator iter = container.begin(); iter != container.end(); ++iter)
    AddToUpdate(iter, update);
```

I am looking at the for_each STL algorithm as it seems to fit my needs.

I was wondering if, given the use of a second input parameter to the function being applied to the container, whether it's possible to refactor this to use a standard STL algorithm without using member variables or other loopholes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The various `std::bind1st`/`std::bind2nd` and the [Boost.bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/bind/bind.html) library were created to solve your problem (that is common to almost anyone who used the STL algorithms), but often they just seem a workaround instead of a solution.

Fortunately, with the upcoming C++ standard the long-awaited addition of [lambda functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Lambda_functions_and_expressions) should solve definitively the problem. However, notice that, since `std::for_each` calls the functor passing the dereferenced iterator (i.e. the actual value being considered) your `AddToUpdate` function shouldn't accept the iterator, but the value.

In such case, it would be something like this:

```
Update update;
std::foreach(container.begin(); container.end(); [ & update](TypeOfTheValue Value) {
    AddToUpdate(Value, update);
});
```

Comment: Another option is to write a functor to do the work. That would achieve behavior similar to the lambda version, but without requiring compiler support for C++0x.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use  `std::bind2nd()` - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/bind2nd/

Basically it return a unary function object from function with 2 arguments, where the second argument is fixed.

This is how your code should look like with `for_each` and `bind2nd`:

```
Update update;
for_each(container.begin(), container.end(), bind2nd(ptr_fun(AddToUpdate), update));
```

**Edit.** As Matteo noticed the first argument of `AddToUpdate` has to be type of value in container, not an iterator.

Comment: But that only works on functors deriving from `std::binary_function`, not on functions.

Comment: Right, edited. I am used to `boost::bind`, so I forgotten how much pain was pure STL.

Comment: An issue with this approach is that it cannot be used with references, as bind2nd attempts to also use the second parameter as a reference, resulting in an illegal reference to a reference.  It looks like I'd missed this bit of info in my initial question.

Comment: You could always use `boost::bind`. I find it more comfortable that using STL.